# Trying to filter data that contains "-M", but it's giving me an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that filters a lot of values, but when I try to change "-M" to " "(nothing) in a worksheet, it gives me an error.
The error that is given to me is

> 'Application-defined or object-defined error' 'Run-Time error 4004'.

Here is my code:

```
Cells.Replace What:="-m", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
        , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: Do you have any formulas that include `-m` in them, e.g. `-M1`? Should the `xlPart` perhaps be `xlWhole`?

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. Try qualifying `Cells` with actual worksheet name as in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Cells.Replace`... Also try to perform this replacement manually in excel. Sometimes this highlights the problem as this type of error indicates an issue with Excel rather than VBA, hence the name 'Application-defined'.

Comment: Just to elaborate why you should try manually: Say you have a named constant called 'MyConst' and you have a formula '=A1-MyConst'. If you replace '-M' the formula becomes '=A1yConst', which is an invalid formula. This upsets excel which shows you a message of its anger. However, VBA only says the application (excel in this case) was unhappy. Therefore, performing this action manually **might** highlight the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Cells.Replace What:="-m", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I have the same problem, but once I removed the "formulaversion" argument, it works. Also according to Microsoft Online Document, the "formulaversion" is not one of the expected argument for the replace function.<sup>*</sup>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace

<sup>*</sup> The addition of the **optional** *formulaversion* argument to `Range.Replace` seems to coincide with the introduction of Dynamic Array formulas. As of the writing of this answer, the documentation has not been updated to reflect this. Since it is optional, it can probably be safely dropped. It *should* be dropped if your version of Excel does not support Dynamic Array formulas.

Comment: The documentation hasn't been refreshed yet. The new `formulaversion` argument coincides with the introduction of Dynamic Array formulas, I believe.

Comment: Just jump into Object Browser and conformed my finding. 

"Function Replace(What, Replacement, [LookAt], [SearchOrder], [MatchCase], [MatchByte], [SearchFormat], [ReplaceFormat]) As Boolean
    Member of Excel.Range"

Comment: Then you don't have the version of Excel with dynamic array formulas.

Comment: I am in Excel 2013. Is it available in Excel 2016? May be PedroB is in Excel 2013. If so it means it is the Excel version.

Comment: It probably can be dropped, yes, it's an optional argument, but see the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWFqG.png

Comment: It worked for me in my computer! Just need to try it in the other one!! Even so, thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, hopefully you're ok with the edit. It was a good answer, I upvoted but also added that info for anyone who does have the latest version of Excel.